# MacBook Pro Retina 2013 crashes on wake up

Tags: mac, macos, sleep-wake, macbook-pro

I have late 2013 rMBP and very often it fails to wake up after closing the lid. It crashes and restarts.

How do I find out which process or application causes those failed attempts to wake up?

I try reading the console logs, but I can't understand much from it.

Should I look for something specific? Some other log file?

Here's an excerpt from the console log, I opened the lid at 12:28

```
4/10/14 06:15:08.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 444887.011559: wl0: powerChange: *** BONJOUR/MDNS OFFLOADS ARE NOT RUNNING.
4/10/14 06:15:08.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
4/10/14 06:15:08.544 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 06:15:08.547 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).

4/10/14 12:28:51.000 bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1397125731 0

4/10/14 07:15:06.301 hidd[67]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
4/10/14 07:15:06.572 airportd[81]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “Kromidarevo”. Bailing on auto-join.
4/10/14 07:15:08.193 ntpd[89]: ntpd: wake time set +0.459332 s
4/10/14 07:15:08.207 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 07:15:08.210 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 07:16:38.407 ntpd[89]: ntpd: wake time set -0.140533 s
4/10/14 07:16:38.422 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 07:16:38.425 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 08:16:37.301 hidd[67]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
4/10/14 08:16:37.574 airportd[81]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “Kromidarevo”. Bailing on auto-join.
4/10/14 08:16:40.034 ntpd[89]: ntpd: wake time set +1.297961 s
4/10/14 08:16:40.051 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 08:16:40.054 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 09:18:09.290 hidd[67]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
4/10/14 09:18:09.571 airportd[81]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “Kromidarevo”. Bailing on auto-join.
4/10/14 09:18:10.824 ntpd[89]: ntpd: wake time set +0.237189 s
4/10/14 09:18:10.837 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 09:18:10.849 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 10:18:54.304 hidd[67]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
4/10/14 10:18:54.585 airportd[81]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “Kromidarevo”. Bailing on auto-join.
4/10/14 10:18:56.790 ntpd[89]: ntpd: wake time set +1.201746 s
4/10/14 10:18:56.807 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 10:18:56.810 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 11:19:56.301 hidd[67]: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
4/10/14 11:19:56.578 airportd[81]: _doAutoJoin: Already associated to “Kromidarevo”. Bailing on auto-join.
4/10/14 11:19:57.048 spindump[40895]: No microstackshots found
4/10/14 11:19:58.537 ntpd[89]: ntpd: wake time set +0.940797 s
4/10/14 11:19:58.555 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
4/10/14 11:19:58.561 com.apple.time[503]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).

4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.appstore" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.bookstore" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.eventmonitor" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.iokit.power" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.mail" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.MessageTracer" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.performance" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Longterm timer threshold: 1000 ms
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: PMAP: PCID enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: PMAP: Supervisor Mode Execute Protection enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: vm_page_bootstrap: 4036112 free pages and 125424 wired pages
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: kext submap [0xffffff7f807a6000 - 0xffffff8000000000], kernel text [0xffffff8000200000 - 0xffffff80007a6000]
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: zone leak detection enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: "vm_compressor_mode" is 4
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: standard timeslicing quantum is 10000 us
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: standard background quantum is 2500 us
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: mig_table_max_displ = 74
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: TSC Deadline Timer supported and enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=1 LocalApicId=0 Enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=2 LocalApicId=2 Enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=3 LocalApicId=4 Enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=4 LocalApicId=6 Enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=5 LocalApicId=1 Enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=6 LocalApicId=3 Enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=7 LocalApicId=5 Enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=8 LocalApicId=7 Enabled
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for TMSafetyNet
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Safety net for Time Machine (TMSafetyNet)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Sandbox
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Seatbelt sandbox policy (Sandbox)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Quarantine
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Quarantine policy (Quarantine)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Copyright (c) 1982, 1986, 1989, 1991, 1993
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: MAC Framework successfully initialized
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: using 16384 buffer headers and 10240 cluster IO buffer headers
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleKeyStore starting (BUILT: Sep 29 2013 19:37:40)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: IOAPIC: Version 0x20 Vectors 64:87
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: ACPI: sleep states S3 S4 S5
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: pci (build 20:00:24 Jan 16 2014), flags 0x63008, pfm64 (39 cpu) 0x7f80000000, 0x80000000
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Sleep failure code 0x00000000 0x13006c00
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: console relocated to 0x7f80020000
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 13, devices 14 ]
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHIType2::setupPowerSavings - GPE based runtime power management
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: SATA WARNING: IDENTIFY DEVICE checksum not implemented.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: mcache: 8 CPU(s), 64 bytes CPU cache line size
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: mbinit: done [128 MB total pool size, (85/42) split]
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Pthread support ABORTS when sync kernel primitives misused
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: rooting via boot-uuid from /chosen: 4A0A6853-04DE-36F0-99AF-BE6990B1916D
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Waiting on <dict ID="0"><key>IOProviderClass</key><string ID="1">IOResources</string><key>IOResourceMatch</key><string ID="2">boot-uuid-media</string></dict>
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib kmod start
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless kmod start
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib load succeeded
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless load succeeded
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Got boot device = IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP05@1C,4/IOPP/SSD0@0/AppleAHCI/PRT0@0/IOAHCIDevice@0/AppleAHCIDiskDriver/IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice/IOBlockStorageDriver/APPLE SSD SM1024F Media/IOGUIDPartitionScheme/Customer@2
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: BSD root: disk0s2, major 1, minor 2
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: jnl: b(1, 2): replay_journal: from: 24248832 to: 35287552 (joffset 0x1321b000)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: srom rev:11
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 0.478008: ChangeVCO => vco:960, xtalF:40, frac: 98, ndivMode: 3, ndivint: 24
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 0.478015: Data written into the PLL_CNTRL_ADDR2: 00000c31
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 0.478034: Data written into the PLL_CNTRL_ADDR3 (Fractional): 0000100e
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 0.484873: BTCOEXIST off 
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 0.485024: BRCM tunables:
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 0.485028:   pullmode[1] txringsize[  256] txsendqsize[1024] reapmin[   32] reapcount[  128]
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 0.485602: wl0: Broadcom BCM43a0, vendorID[0x14e4] BAR0[0xc1a00004]
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: 6.30.223.154 (r420397)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: jnl: b(1, 2): journal replay done.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 000000000820 0x5ac 0x8406 0x820, 3
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff80249a3c00>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 11 unplug = 0
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: IOThunderboltSwitch<0xffffff80249a3c00>(0x0)::listenerCallback - Thunderbolt HPD packet for route = 0x0 port = 12 unplug = 0
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Macintosh HD on device root_device
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: XCPM: registered
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: hfs: Removed 348 orphaned / unlinked files and 14 directories 
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
4/10/14 12:28:52.009 com.apple.launchd[1]: *** launchd[1] has started up. ***
4/10/14 12:28:52.009 com.apple.launchd[1]: *** Shutdown logging is enabled. ***
4/10/14 12:28:53.392 com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100000 created
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: IO80211Controller::dataLinkLayerAttachComplete():  adding AppleEFINVRAM notification
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: IO80211Interface::efiNVRAMPublished():  
4/10/14 12:28:53.457 com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Entering service
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
4/10/14 12:28:53.464 configd[18]: dhcp_arp_router: en0 SSID unavailable
4/10/14 12:28:53.486 UserEventAgent[11]: Failed to copy info dictionary for bundle /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/alfUIplugin.plugin
4/10/14 08:16:40.626 GitHub[19289]: Error checking for updates: NSError { domain: SQRLUpdaterErrorDomain, code: 7, description: "Update check failed", recoverySuggestion: "The server sent an invalid response. Try again later.", underlying error: NSError { domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: 3840, description: "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.", failureReason: "The data is not in the correct format.", userInfo: {
    NSDebugDescription = "No value.";
} }, userInfo: {
    NSDebugDescription = "No value.";
    SQRLUpdaterServerDataErrorKey = <>;
} }
4/10/14 12:28:53.506 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Inactive
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::init
4/10/14 08:16:40.627 GitHub[19289]: [19289] (v175) __52-[GitHubAppDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:]_block_invoke125 [Line 132] Error checking for updates: NSError { domain: SQRLUpdaterErrorDomain, code: 7, description: "Update check failed", recoverySuggestion: "The server sent an invalid response. Try again later.", underlying error: NSError { domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: 3840, description: "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.", failureReason: "The data is not in the correct format.", userInfo: {
    NSDebugDescription = "No value.";
} }, userInfo: {
    NSDebugDescription = "No value.";
    SQRLUpdaterServerDataErrorKey = <>;
} }
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::probe
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::start
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::start: fS2DeviceRegs=0xffffff81d7015000 (len=65536)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::start: fS2DeviceMemory=0xffffff81d72dd000 (len=268435456)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::start: fISPRegsMem=0xffffff8025b73080 (len=1048576)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: virtual bool AppleCamIn::start(IOService *): about to configure DDR
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key LsNM (kSMCKeyNotFound)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR LsNM kSMCKeyNotFound(0x84) fKeyHashTable=0x0
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcGetLightshowVers ERROR: smcReadKey LsNM failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcPublishLightshowVersion ERROR: smcGetLightshowVers failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: smcPublishLightshowVersion failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Previous Shutdown Cause: 3
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AGC: 3.4.35, HW version=4.0.8 [3.2.8], flags:0, features:20600
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe ProductID - 0x8289 FirmwareVersion - 0x0079
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- completed -- result = TRUE -- 0x9000 ****
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: **** [BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- Completed -- 0x9000 ****
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: NVDAStartup: Official
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: Waiting for DSMOS...
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: NVDAGK100HAL loaded and registered
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: init
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: probe
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: com_intel_driver_EnergyDriver[0xffffff8025980200]::start(0xffffff8024290c00)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: start
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][staticBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Received Bluetooth Controller register service notification -- 0x9000 
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][start] -- completed
4/10/14 12:28:53.561 configd[18]: setting hostname to "bmbp.local"
4/10/14 12:28:53.563 configd[18]: network changed.
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController::setConfigState] calling registerService
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHCIController][protectedBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Connected to the transport successfully -- 0x96c0 -- 0x4000 -- 0x9000 ****
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: DSMOS has arrived
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: IOPPF - IODeviceTree:/efi/platform/StartupPowerEvents: 0x0
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: IOPPF: XCPM mode
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: hmm.. mismatch sizes: 3100 vs 20
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: save_ddr_phy_regs: saving 127 DDR PHY shmoo-calibrated registers 
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::initACPI - status = 0x00000000, acpi_path_object = 0xffffff802443d7c0
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::initACPI - status = 0x00000000, acpi_path = IOACPIPlane:/_SB/PCI0@0/RP04@1c0003/CMRA@0
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::initACPI - status = 0x00000000, acpi_device_entry = 0xffffff80248f7200
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::initACPI - status = 0x00000000, fACPIDevice = 0xffffff80248f7200
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::initACPI - status = 0x00000000, fACPIPowerEnabled = 1
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::start - link control offset in PCI bridge = 0x50
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::start - pmcsr offset in PCI bridge = 0xa4
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::power_off_hardware
4/10/14 12:28:53.812 UserEventAgent[11]: assertion failed: 13C64: com.apple.telemetry + 22864 [FDCB4ECA-3C5D-394A-BAEF-F6555BEB4239]: 0x0
4/10/14 12:28:53.812 UserEventAgent[11]: assertion failed: 13C64: com.apple.telemetry + 22864 [FDCB4ECA-3C5D-394A-BAEF-F6555BEB4239]: 0x0
4/10/14 12:28:53.814 fseventsd[39]: event logs in /.fseventsd out of sync with volume.  destroying old logs. (991513 2 991604)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0x9000 ****
4/10/14 09:18:10.423 Viber[521]: setShowsApplicationBadge: is not yet implemented for the NSApp dockTile
4/10/14 12:28:53.988 fseventsd[39]: log dir: /.fseventsd getting new uuid: B0998E99-A89C-415D-B327-04BDC92F282C
4/10/14 12:28:54.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::initForPM
4/10/14 12:28:54.000 kernel[0]: AppleCamIn::systemWakeCall - messageType = 0xE0000340
4/10/14 12:28:54.000 kernel[0]: en1: promiscuous mode enable succeeded
4/10/14 12:28:54.000 kernel[0]: en2: promiscuous mode enable succeeded
4/10/14 12:28:54.065 hidd[68]: void __IOHIDPlugInLoadBundles(): Loaded 0 HID plugins
4/10/14 12:28:54.066 hidd[68]: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
4/10/14 12:28:54.112 com.apple.usbmuxd[46]: usbmuxd-327.4 on Feb 12 2014 at 14:54:33, running 64 bit
4/10/14 12:28:54.000 kernel[0]: VM Swap Subsystem is ON
4/10/14 12:28:54.133 awacsd[78]: Starting awacsd connectivity_executables-97 (Sep 12 2013 20:24:33)
4/10/14 12:28:54.136 awacsd[78]: InnerStore CopyAllZones: no info in Dynamic Store
4/10/14 12:28:54.162 mDNSResponder[60]: mDNSResponder mDNSResponder-522.90.2 (Nov  3 2013 18:51:09) starting OSXVers 13
4/10/14 12:28:54.168 loginwindow[63]: Login Window Application Started
4/10/14 12:28:54.189 mds[59]: (Normal) FMW: FMW 0 0
4/10/14 12:28:54.201 systemkeychain[93]: done file: /var/run/systemkeychaincheck.done
4/10/14 12:28:54.212 configd[18]: network changed.
4/10/14 12:28:54.213 configd[18]: network changed: DNS*
4/10/14 12:28:54.220 mDNSResponder[60]: D2D_IPC: Loaded
4/10/14 12:28:54.220 mDNSResponder[60]: D2DInitialize succeeded
4/10/14 12:28:54.222 WindowServer[98]: Server is starting up
4/10/14 12:28:54.223 mDNSResponder[60]:   4: Listening for incoming Unix Domain Socket client requests
4/10/14 12:28:54.226 WindowServer[98]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
4/10/14 12:28:54.226 WindowServer[98]: Session 256 released (1 references)
4/10/14 12:28:54.238 WindowServer[98]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
4/10/14 12:28:54.240 WindowServer[98]: init_page_flip: page flip mode is on
4/10/14 12:28:54.253 networkd[110]: networkd.110 built Sep 12 2013 15:08:27
4/10/14 12:28:54.273 apsd[80]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
4/10/14 12:28:54.349 digest-service[87]: label: default
4/10/14 12:28:54.349 digest-service[87]:  dbname: od:/Local/Default
4/10/14 12:28:54.349 digest-service[87]:  mkey_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/m-key
4/10/14 12:28:54.349 digest-service[87]:  acl_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/kadmind.acl
4/10/14 12:28:54.350 digest-service[87]: digest-request: uid=0
4/10/14 12:28:54.418 airportd[82]: airportdProcessDLILEvent: en0 attached (up)
4/10/14 12:28:54.000 kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm4360_P2PInterface::init name <p2p0> role 1
4/10/14 12:28:54.000 kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm4360_P2PInterface::init() <p2p> role 1
4/10/14 12:28:54.510 digest-service[87]: digest-request: netr probe 0
4/10/14 12:28:54.511 digest-service[87]: digest-request: init request
4/10/14 12:28:54.520 digest-service[87]: digest-request: init return domain: BUILTIN server: BMBP indomain was: <NULL>
4/10/14 12:28:54.556 locationd[65]: NBB-Could not get UDID for stable refill timing, falling back on random
4/10/14 12:28:54.570 MAMP[125]: Starting MAMP Apache web server
4/10/14 12:28:54.625 locationd[65]: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
4/10/14 12:28:54.776 locationd[65]: locationd was started after an unclean shutdown
4/10/14 12:28:54.793 MAMP[139]: Starting MAMP MySQL server
4/10/14 12:28:54.888 WindowServer[98]: Found 62 modes for display 0x00000000 [36, 26]
4/10/14 12:28:54.892 WindowServer[98]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
4/10/14 12:28:54.895 WindowServer[98]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
4/10/14 12:28:54.897 WindowServer[98]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
4/10/14 12:28:54.900 WindowServer[98]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
4/10/14 12:28:54.912 WindowServer[98]: mux_initialize: Mode is dynamic
4/10/14 12:28:54.913 WindowServer[98]: Found 62 modes for display 0x00000000 [36, 26]
4/10/14 10:18:55.297 Viber[521]: setShowsApplicationBadge: is not yet implemented for the NSApp dockTile
4/10/14 12:28:54.915 WindowServer[98]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
4/10/14 12:28:54.915 WindowServer[98]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
4/10/14 12:28:54.915 WindowServer[98]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
4/10/14 12:28:54.994 com.apple.launchd[1]: (0x7f8be2d0fde0.anonymous.nohup[436]) assertion failed: 13C64: launchd + 73282 [425516B6-9F3E-342F-87B3-EC461EBA6A1A]: 0x0
4/10/14 12:28:54.994 com.apple.launchd[1]: (0x7f8be2d0fde0.anonymous.nohup[436]) Switching sessions is not allowed in the system Mach bootstrap.
4/10/14 12:28:54.994 com.apple.launchd[1]: (0x7f8be2d0fde0.anonymous.nohup[436]) _vprocmgr_switch_to_session(): kr = 0x44c
4/10/14 12:28:54.995 com.apple.launchd[1]: (0x7f8be2d0fde0.anonymous.nohup[437]) assertion failed: 13C64: launchd + 73282 [425516B6-9F3E-342F-87B3-EC461EBA6A1A]: 0x0
4/10/14 12:28:54.995 com.apple.launchd[1]: (0x7f8be2d0fde0.anonymous.nohup[437]) Switching sessions is not allowed in the system Mach bootstrap.
4/10/14 12:28:54.995 com.apple.launchd[1]: (0x7f8be2d0fde0.anonymous.nohup[437]) _vprocmgr_switch_to_session(): kr = 0x44c
4/10/14 12:28:55.131 WindowServer[98]: WSMachineUsesNewStyleMirroring: true
4/10/14 12:28:55.135 WindowServer[98]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (0, 0)[3840 x 2160], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
4/10/14 12:28:55.135 WindowServer[98]: Display 0x003f0041: GL mask 0x20; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 5, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
4/10/14 12:28:55.135 WindowServer[98]: Display 0x003f0040: GL mask 0x10; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 4, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
4/10/14 10:20:25.595 ReportCrash[40894]: Invoking spindump for pid=521 wakeups_rate=199 duration=227 because of excessive wakeups
4/10/14 12:28:55.135 WindowServer[98]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
4/10/14 12:28:55.135 WindowServer[98]: Display 0x04280882: GL mask 0x5; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 62 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model a022, S/N 0, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xfd6e905353b752245892f9f7ec52cef3
4/10/14 12:28:55.136 WindowServer[98]: WSSetWindowTransform: Singular matrix
4/10/14 12:28:55.136 WindowServer[98]: WSSetWindowTransform: Singular matrix
4/10/14 12:28:55.136 WindowServer[98]: WSSetWindowTransform: Singular matrix
4/10/14 12:28:55.138 WindowServer[98]: Display 0x04280882: GL mask 0x5; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 62 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model a022, S/N 0, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xfd6e905353b752245892f9f7ec52cef3
4/10/14 12:28:55.138 WindowServer[98]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: disable VIBER app.

Comment: what network? the wifi? why should i do that?

Comment: what do you mean 'disable' Viber? uninstall? why?

Comment: That is what I read in your console log as possible reasons.

Comment: Your Console log should start with ..... kernel[0]: Wake reason: EC.LidOpen (User)
and tell us what is happening after that

Comment: Edited the question, check it out

Comment: → Birowsky: please insert within the OQ under which power mode was your rMBP: battery | power supply.

Answer (score 2):

These 2 lines of network initialization look suspicious:

```
4/10/14 12:28:54.000 kernel[0]: en1: promiscuous mode enable succeeded
4/10/14 12:28:54.000 kernel[0]: en2: promiscuous mode enable succeeded
```

This mode may cause your network interfaces to drain your battery when on this mode of power supply.
Did you install anything that may have switched your 2 network interfaces (Ethernet & AirPort) in promiscuous mode?

[To be confirmed:] *Softwares as* `Skype` *,* `Viber` *might tune your network in this mode without warning you.*

These 4 lines indicate that you SMC should be reinitialized:

```
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key LsNM (kSMCKeyNotFound)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR LsNM kSMCKeyNotFound(0x84) fKeyHashTable=0x0
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcGetLightshowVers ERROR: smcReadKey LsNM failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcPublishLightshowVersion ERROR: smcGetLightshowVers failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
4/10/14 12:28:53.000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: smcPublishLightshowVersion failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
```

Read this Apple documentation: [Resetting the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964).

Comment: Thanx for the effort Daniel, all I can do is vote you up since I don't have this issue any more since the 2 complete reformats. However, now, i get a minute of black screen after every other system wakeup. The irony. :}

Comment: Does your initial problem and this new "black screen" happen on battery?

Comment: Both. On battery and off battery.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to SafeSleep or SmartSleep on the OS. This system puts all your current memory (your RAM) onto the disk, so that it can power down the RAM, save energy, and keep the current working state of your computer, even if you ran out of battery power, changed batteries, etc.

Problem is, it’s slow. And buggy. Often when waking from sleep by opening the lid, the MacBook will remain in sleep.

Open a Terminal window and type this command:

```
pmset -g | grep hibernatemode
```

That should return you something like “hibernatemode 3″.  Mode 3 keeps your RAM powered during sleep to allow super fast wake-up, but also writes an image file of all memory onto disk in case power is lost.

To change the hibernate safe sleep setting to not create an image file on the disk, i.e. mode 0 (mode zero, not the letter ‘o’), enter the following in a Terminal window:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
```

Enter your password when asked to do so. This prevents Safe Sleep from saving your memory contents to disk, in large part the cause of not being able to wake MacBook’s from sleep.

Comment: What do you mean buggy? Hibernation has been around forever. Disabling hibernation means wasting a lot of power when lid closed.

Comment: Hello Birowsky.  Hibernate has been around forever, correct.  Do you use Chrome by any chance?

Comment: Also, you may want to look at this: http://zoooot.com/2927/viber-crash-on-os-x-mavericks

Comment: Yes, I use chrome as my main development enviroment

Comment: I updated the log in the question with a fresh crash. Tell me if you see something interesting. Or if the Viber thing persists. Thanx

Comment: @Birowsky you could read your log yourself to answer the question about Viber. I would be helpful if you tell us did you change something we need to know before spending time looking at your log to see the difference to the previous log.

Comment: @Buscar웃, nope, I did not change anything in the system. I updated it just for a cross-referencing purpose. As for Viber, this is the only message there (wsApplicationBadge: is not yet implemented for the NSApp dockTile) and from what I read here http://goo.gl/f3guH4 its not a big deal. Just some icon painting issue. I wouldn't expect the whole system to hang because of that?